# How to make a histogram-like plot?

Tags: plotting, syntax, histograms

Consider the following data:

```
data={{0., 0.391429}, {0.2, 0.391429}, {0.4, 0.422857}, {0.6, 
  0.46875}, {0.8, 0.53125}, {1., 0.509009}, {1.2, 0.535885}, {1.4, 
  0.587065}, {1.6, 0.589474}, {1.8, 0.63354}, {2., 0.64375}, {2.2, 
  0.614035}, {2.4, 0.683824}, {2.6, 0.697987}, {2.8, 0.657658}, {3., 
  0.669811}, {3.2, 0.754902}, {3.4, 0.73913}, {3.6, 0.731959}, {3.8, 
  0.758621}, {4., 0.833333}, {4.2, 0.671875}, {4.4, 0.793651}, {4.6, 
  0.875}, {4.8, 0.764706}, {5., 0.833333}, {5.2, 0.905405}, {5.4, 
  0.818182}, {5.6, 0.865385}, {5.8, 0.9}, {6., 0.897959}, {6.2, 
  0.860465}, {6.4, 0.875}, {6.6, 0.897959}, {6.8, 0.969697}, {7., 
  0.92}, {7.2, 0.775}, {7.4, 0.96875}, {7.6, 0.954545}, {7.8, 
  0.961538}, {8., 0.9375}, {8.2, 0.875}, {8.4, 0.878788}, {8.6, 
  0.975}, {8.8, 0.970588}, {9., 0.916667}, {9.2, 0.961538}, {9.4, 
  0.588235}, {9.6, 0.}, {9.8, 0.}, {10., 0.}};
```

Its first column is the beginning of the bin, while the second column is the number of entries per bin. I would like to plot it as a histogram. A way to do this that I know is to interpolate the data with `InterpolationOrder->0`:

```
dataint[z_] = 
 Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0][z]
Plot[dataint[z], {z, 1, 7.7}]
```

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWLkS.png)

Is there any other way to obtain exactly the same plot but using `ListPlot` for the initial `data`?

Comment: Try this one `ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0]`

Comment: `BarChart[data[[All, 2]], 
 ChartLabels -> (Rotate[#, \[Pi]/2] & /@ data[[All, 1]])]` ?

Comment: One comment. If you overlay in the same panel the plot of the interpolation function (as shown by @John Taylor) and the list plot with the embedded interpolation option (as shown by @yarchik) you will get a shift between them equal to the bin size i.e. 0.2. Of course this goes away if you do plot the interpolation function of dataint[z - 0.2].

Comment: `ListStepPlot[data, Filling -> Bottom]` almost works but there are still no vertical lines between all the bars like in `Histogram[]`.

If you really want to perfectly emulate the behavior of histogram with the bar-like elements, you might have to go back to interpolating and use the `ExtentSize` option with `DiscretePlot`:
`int = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]`
`DiscretePlot[int[i], {i, 0, 10, 0.2}, ExtentSize -> Full]`

I think @Syed 's `BarChart` idea is good, but I don't like how smooshed all the x-axis labels end up.

Comment: Perhaps easier to construct the Piecewise
$$hst[x_] = 
 Piecewise@   
  Array[({data[[#, 2]], data[[#, 1]] <= x <= data[[# + 1, 1]]} &), 
   Length[data] - 1]$$